# Structure Members - Address Overlap

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, structure

In this program I have declared a structure along with few members and I have used an array of two elements as instances for this particular structure . I have used a 5 element array in this structure. One peculiar thing is, in the main function when I try to get the address of the non existent 6th element of 5 element array, I get the address of the first member integer of the next structure. Why there was no error show when I tried to access a non existing array element and why two members are having the same address ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
 struct {int num1,num2; char s1; int *ptr; int abc[5]; }a[2];

void main(){

      int start, last; 

      start = &a[1].num1;

      last = &a[0].num1;

      printf("\nSize of the Structure : %d Bytes", start-last);

      printf("\naddress of num1 in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].num1);

      printf("\naddress of num2 in structure  a[0] is %d", &a[0].num2);

      printf("\naddress of char in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].s1);

      printf("\naddress of ptr in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].ptr);

      printf("\naddress of I element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].abc[0]);

      printf("\naddress of II element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].abc[1]);

      printf("\naddress of III element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].abc[2]);

      printf("\naddress of IV element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].abc[3]);

      printf("\naddress of V element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].abc[4]);

      **printf("\naddress of VI element in the 5 element array abc[5] in structure a[0] is %d", &a[0].abc[5]);

      printf("\naddress of num1 in structure a[1] is %d", &a[1].num1);**

      printf("\n");


  }

kevin@kevin-desktop:~/Documents/programs$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

kevin@kevin-desktop:~/Documents/programs$ gcc structure_size.c -o structure_size
structure_size.c: In function ‘main’:
structure_size.c:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
structure_size.c:17: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
structure_size.c:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:23: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:25: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’
structure_size.c:27: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’
structure_size.c:29: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:31: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:33: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:35: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:37: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:39: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
structure_size.c:41: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
kevin@kevin-desktop:~/Documents/programs$ ./structure_size

Size of the Structure : 36 Bytes
address of num1 in structure a[0] is 134520896
address of num2 in structure  a[0] is 134520900
address of char in structure a[0] is 134520904
address of ptr in structure a[0] is 134520908
address of I element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is 134520912
address of II element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is 134520916
address of III element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is 134520920
address of IV element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is 134520924
address of V element in array abc[5] in structure a[0] is 134520928
**address of VI element in the 5 element array abc[5] in structure a[0] is 134520932
address of num1 in structure a[1] is 134520932**
kevin@kevin-desktop:~/Documents/programs$
```

Comment: Because you're in C (and for that case 2nd structure is allocated in memory just after the first one). Welcome.

Comment: If you index an array out of bounds, you have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you're doing is undefined behavior, and compilers are certainly not required to detect and report it.

This is (of course) since doing so would be very hard in general, and also because you can do the same thing "dynamically", which makes it more or less impossible to detect at compile-time.

Remember that C doesn't have run-time checking of array bounds; you can index whatever you want and in most cases the compiler will emit the code do try to do the access. It might be stopped by the operating system, but it might also "just do it" and wreak some havoc into your life.

As @Adriano said, welcome to C! :)

P.S. Pointers should be printed with `%p`, they are not `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is how C works. I think the phenomenon is easier showed in this simplified code:

```
char string[2][5];              // allocates a block of 10 bytes

string == string[0];            // true
string == &string[0][0];        // true
&string[0][5] == &string[1][0]; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your abc array size is 5, means you have a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4].

You are done with 5 elements. But you wrote a[5]. which is out of that structure.

a[2] is implied as (a+2) where 'a' is an address, a = 134520896,

so a + 2 is 134520904

you have 5 elements in array so array will get 20 bytes. i.e. from 134520896 to 134520915.

134520916 is the address of next variable of your array a, and it is not memory of your array a